# finding element in array then swapping using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, boolean, swap

Trying to write a method called bool findElement(int elt)

First traverses elementData to find the element elt.  If found, the method returns true, but also the found element (the left-most one in the case when duplicate elements exist) is moved to the front of the array and swapped with the 0th element.

For example, if the array (pointed by elementData) contained [6, 2, 4, 7, 3] and findElement(7) is called, the function changes the array to [7, 2, 4, 6, 3] and returns true.  If the element was not found in the array, the function just returns false.

this is what i have so far

```
bool findElement(int elt)
{
    double temp2 = elementData[i];
    elementData[i] = elementData[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        if (elementData[i] == elt)
            return true && elementData[0] = temp2;

        else
            false;
    }   
}
```

errors:
size is undefined 
elementData is undefined

This is what it the output should look like

findElement(4) => true
[4, 2, 6, 7, 3]  -- size=5, capacity=8

findElement(1) => false
[3, 2, 6, 7, 4]  -- size=5, capacity=8

Comment: I can only repeat after the compiler that size and elementData are undefined. Also it is entire unclear what are size and capacity and how they are related with each other. Take into account that the parameter of the function has type int while variable temp2 has type double.

Comment: This question looks like homework, so I'm not giving you the final solution! in C++ there is no 'size' keyword. To find the size of an array in C/C++ you can use this macro: #define SIZE_OF_ARRAY(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

Comment: @cabbi this is homework and i cannot use macros. I define size and elementData in another source file.

int ar[5] = { 6, 2, 4, 7, 3 };

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you without knowing how the elements are storred. Are they in a simple (c like) array ? Are they in a C++ stl containner like std::vector ?

If they are in a simple c like array you can do

```
template <typename T>
bool findElement(T element, T* array, size_t size)
{
    T* ptr = std::find(array, array+size, element);
    if (ptr == array+size) return false;
    std::swap(*array, *ptr);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the method bool findElement(int elt) was given by the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define elementData and size before your function definition. Simply like:

```
double elementData[] = {6, 2, 4, 7, 3};
int size = 5;
```

And I think `return true && elementData[0] = temp2;` is not what you want due to short circuit evaluation. You should write like this:

```
if (elementData[i] == elt){
    elementData[0] = temp2;
    return true;
}
else return false;
```

Comment: I define elementData in another source file
int ar[5] = { 6, 2, 4, 7, 3 };
PFArray pf;

Comment: So did you put that file with #include ?

Comment: yes, i #include the header file. here is what i have now 
<pre>
    bool findElement(int elt)
    {
 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  if (elementData[i] == elt){
   elementData[0] = elt;
   return true;
  }
  else return false;
 }
    }
<code>

Comment: yes, i #include the header file. here is what i have now 

     bool findElement(int elt)
     {
 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  if (elementData[i] == elt){
   elementData[0] = elt;
   return true;
  }
  else return false;
 }
     }

Comment: Then you need post more detail about the other file you defined elementData and size plus how you include them.